# Onclick, make <li>item bold

Tags: html, css

is it possible to make the clicked link text bold, through the use of only HTML/css?

```
<body>
    <div id="menu-bg">
        <div id="menu-text">
            <ul id="list">
                <li><a href="experience.php">THE EXPERIENCE</a><br>
                    <a href="services.php">SERVICES</a><br>
                    <a href="adventures.php">ADVENTURE</a><br>
                    <a href="tour.php">TOUR</a><br>
                    <a href="gallery.php">GALLERY</a><br>
                    <a href="reviews.php">REVIEWS</a><br>
                    <a href="location.php">LOCATION</a>
                </li>

         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not really since you need to read the current document location which is dynamic.

Answer (score 11):

try

```
a:visited {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Definitely Yes.

For html/css, you can use:

```
<style>
    li a:active{
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
```

You can also use javascript/jquery on that:

```
$('li a').click(function(e){
    $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try -

```
<style>
ul li a:visited {
     font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
```

write me if problem persists.